# Talk something v. talk about something

Tags: grammar, prepositions, style

Is there any difference between *talk something* and *talk **about** something*? (For example, 'talk politics' and 'talk about politics'.)

Note, I'm talking about instances when the object is some topic, not what is being said (so, 'talk nonsense' and similar is not a matter of this question)

Comment: No, I don't think so. 'Talk' here means 'have a conversation about'.

Comment: *Let's talk turkey* has a completely different meaning from *let's talk **about** turkey.* That particular idiom aside, *let's talk children* (for instance) isn't idiomatic without punctuation (it only makes sense if you add a comma, making it an address **to** children), but *let's talk **about** children* is fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In most contexts, there is no difference. "Lets talk [x]" is an informal, colloquial abbreviation for "let's talk *about* [x]".

There is something of a difference though - the shorter "lets talk [x]" can imply things that the other does not. For example, "*let's talk salary*", following a discussion about potential employment, is really like saying "*tell me what you are offering **me** as a salary*". Talking "about" something is really just naming the subject, and is not always so pointed.

I would also note that I believe it is more common in American English than British English, although it *is* used.

Comment: The usage *He's always talking **shop*** sounds essentially "adverbial" to me, even if strictly speaking, ***shop*** is a noun. But with colloquial *She'll talk **sense** into him* we have what looks more like a conventional transitive verb plus object (comparable to *She'll beat **the living daylights** outta him*).

Comment: @FumbleFingers "talking shop" is an idiom of its own, so I wouldn't cite that as an example. Likewise "talking sense" is different, because "sense" isn't a *subject*. Nobody says "talk about shop" or "talk about sense". I perceive this question is really about situations where they are interchangeable.

Comment: I think syntactically, *talk politics / business / shop* are all essentially *adverbial* usages where we can discard the preposition ***about*** for the first two (*idiomatically*, we can't do this with the third, but *semantically* that would seem to make sense). I'm not sure how I'd analyse *Let's talk **turkey*** though - I suspect that one's more based on talking ***like*** turkeys ("Gobble, gobble", implying intense / focused conversation).

Comment: @FumbleFingers I'm not sure - "let's talk business" is a proposal to discuss business between you and the party you are addressing. "Let's talk *about* business" is far more general - you could mean a general discussion about the business of one party or the other, or perhaps neither.

Comment: Well, I have upvoted your answer, but I'm not convinced that distinction between *talking business* and *talking **about** business* really stands up. Except insofar as the prepositionless form is inherently somewhat *colloquial* (having *slightly* marked syntax), making it less likely to occur in the more formal / literal context of discussions about trade & commerce in general. Hence it's really the probable *context* that invariably steers us towards the *discuss the details of our contractual / financial arrangements* sense.